# как на kivy сделать окно во весь экран?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Я искал информацию по этому вопросу но находил только:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 100)
```

но мне хотелось бы что бы приложение открывалось на весь экран.
Есть ли в kivy какая то функция для получения размера экрана?
Или специальная функция в Config?

Comment: Вот такое попробуйте:Config.set('graphics','fullscreen',True)
Config.write()

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Не знаете, как можно взять размер окна?

Comment: Import Window, print(Window.width), print(Window.height)